# Parse Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var images = new Parse.Query("Images");
var bunny_data = [];

images.equalTo("indexImg","T");
images.find({
    success: function(objects) {
        for(var i = 0;i<=objects.length;i++){
            var object =  objects[i];
            object.get('imgUrl');

        };
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("An error occured :(");
    }
});
console.log(bunny_data);
```

The console is:

> `[]`
>   myjs.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: If an array has length `3` and its indexes are `0`, `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0;i<=objects.length;i++){
```

The `<=` means this loops from `0` to `objects.length` inclusive, but length is an exclusive upper bound on an array’s indices. Use `<` instead.